# Rxjs error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: webpack, rxjs

I'm following the example given in [Rxjs Subject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject):

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject<number>();

// more code...
```

When running npx webpack I get the following error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
| 
> const subject = new Subject<number>();
```

My webpack config is just barebones:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  mode: 'development'
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you're following is using Typescript syntax, whereas your webpack config doesn't seem to be handling typescript. You will need to investigate using typescript. A simple google search will give you many tutorials, but this is a good start: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Alternatively, you could remove the typescript aspects from the example. They are generally the bits with`<`, `>` and `:`